# Advice on a storyboard with UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a storyboard with a home page of buttons, touching a button segues to a nav controller with an embedded tableviewcontroller.  When the tableview appears it is populated with a list of items. When the user touches an item in the list I would like to push either another tableview, or a details view.

Here is what I am doing:

In my ListTableViewController I do this is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];
    DSObject * obj = _m_DSObjects[row];

    if (obj.nType == 1)
    {
        ListTableViewController * tvc = [[ListTableViewController alloc]
                                               initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        MyDetaisViewController * vc = [[MyDetaisViewController alloc]
                                               initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Basically if it is of type 1 (another list) then I want to create another ListViewController, but if it is of type 2, (details) then I want to show my details view.

My problem is that if it is a list, my list does not populate the items.  The cell rows are there, but the are blank, it does not appear to be using my cell prototype.

I am windering if I am doing this wrong and am looking for advice on how to accomplish what I need.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: why don't you create a segue to your new view controller instead of using `pushViewController`? that's kind of the point of storyboards

Comment: ahhh yes, ok, I am new to storyboards, so how do I determine which type to segue to?  An how do i tell it to segue to the right one? Do I use prepareForSegue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach, since you are already using storyboards, would be to create a segue from your `ListTableViewController` to your new list controller, and to your detail view controller.

Then you could change your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];
    DSObject * obj = _m_DSObjects[row];

    if (obj.nType == 1)
    {
        // assuming you named your segue "PresentListController"
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PresentListController" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {   // assuming you named your segue "PresentDetailsController"
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PresentDetailsController" sender:self];
    }
}
```

If you need to pass parameters to any of them you can use `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ListTableViewController class]]) {

        ListTableViewController* listController = (ListTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;            
        listController.someParam = someValue;

        return;        
    }

    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MyDetailsViewController class]]) {

        MyDetailsViewController* detailsController = (MyDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailsController.someOtherParam = someOtherValue;

        return;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In `prepareForSegue` instead of checking for the `class` of the `destinationViewController` you could use `segue.identifier` check for the proper segue, just another way to check where the segue is going.

Comment: Yes, that's it!!  Thank you, I am new to storyboards and could not figure out how to create the two segues. I needed to hang them off of my ListTableViewController... guess i should have thought of that!!  Anyway, thanks for the help!!

Comment: jere, one small issue related to this that maybe you can help with.  I could potentially have n number of levels so by using performSegueWithIdentifier I only have a fixed # of levels, i.e. 1.  However, everything works great, but if my list view needs to display another list then I cannot segue to PresentListController.. for example.

Comment: ok so let me get it straight. you are showing a list of items, and when you tap on one you can either go to a details view, or to a list view. if you go to the list view, when you tap on one of those items you could go to another list view, right?

Comment: Yes, but I think I just figured it out... what I did was create two list view and two detail objects both using the same class. Then I created a segue from and to each other. It appears to work flawlessly. Do you think I will encounter any issues?